# Possible to avoid code changes during schema changes when using Jdbctemplate?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

When using spring's `JdbcTemplate`, I am using the row mapper to map results coming back.

The benefit with this is that there are less places where I have to change my code if I change my mysql schema etc.

Are there any other tips on how to minimize changes in code when adding/removing columns in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are retrieving columns by name (`SELECT col1, col2, col3`) you will be immune to adding and rearranging of columns. Never use `SELECT *`.

However if you are removing columns, you have no choice. In fact, how was this suppose to work? Previously you fetched e.g. `price` column and used it in your business layer. Now the column does not exist - how to handle this?

But adding columns is safe, unless new columns are non-nullable. In this case you will have a problem when adding new records, since `VALUES` statement won't include new columns. Optional columns are fine.

Answer (score 0):

One tip is to not do `SELECT *`, select on specific columns so in case you add stuff you don't break your code :)